# Looking for short horror story about two kids and a spell book

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror, spells

I’ve been looking around for a collection of short stories that contained one in particular. A brother and sister discover a book of magic in their grandparents’ basement. The girl begins using the spells to torment her brother, eventually turning into a large bug to fly after him. He swats it to the ground and stumbles, crushing / smearing it on the floor. He runs up the stairs, trying hard to forget what he saw when the spell began to wear off.

It’s such a horrible image / scenario that left a lasting impression on my adolescent mind, I need to find this story lol. I read it in the late 80’s so it isn’t new; it might even have been in a literature schoolbook! Has anybody heard of this story?

Answer (score 6):

I believe it was the story *A Spell for Jonathan* by Thomas F. Monteleone. I read it in the anthology [*Horror Tales: Spirits, Spells & the Unknown*](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2008/12/horror-tales-spirits-spells-unknown.html) (1974).

I found another website that showed the illustration from the book that helped me confirm my memory. The cat was the culprit.

[image]

[image]